# Printing values in array

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to print the first value in the array I declared:

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .data
array db "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"    

fmt db "%d",0

section .text
_main:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ebx, array
    mov eax, [ebx]
    push eax
    push fmt
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    pop eax

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp

    ret
```

However, the output isn't `1`, it's some really large number. I thought by putting quotes around each integer, I would be printing the symbol, not the equivalent ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You use `db`, which means define byte, single character while you seem to expect an integer in the format, `%d`.

You should use `dd` instead and remove the quotes:

```
array dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
fmt db "%d", 0
```

or use `%c` if you want to print a char:

```
array dd "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
fmt db "%c", 0
```

plus, here:

```
add esp, 4
```

should be:

```
add esp, 8
```

you pushed two arguments.